# Best oscilator scheme for watch crystal

Tags: crystal

I wonder, what's the best oscillator scheme to use with watch crystals(32kHz) to get optimal stability & precision? (provided that temperature is stable, digital correction is out of this topic).

Typical solution is pierce oscillator, but what's the optimal swing/voltage?
I have a feeling that sine-wave generator should put less stress on the crystal.

So, what's the best & less stressful oscillator scheme for watch crystals?

That is for digital clock, so long-term stability is important (crystal will be temperature-stabilized & corrected for aging).

Comment: this seems like a heavy opinion question. What is better? What is optimal stability & precision? What defines best and least stressful?

Comment: @Kortuk Well, this seems straightforward to me: The more stability the better. I guess driving crystal at excessive swing or improper load or improper waveform might cause it to age faster.

Comment: so cost plays no part? the best stability and life and we are golden?

Comment: Yes, as long as we are not going over 1000$ in parts :-D

Comment: With that kind of budget ($1000), you can do some fancy things.  Temperature control is well within range.  Can you get a used HP cesmium clock for that money?

Comment: Temperature control is not included here, I am doing it any way, but I don't think it would eat more than a couple of bucks. Price range for used atomic clocks is in fact very interesting :-D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what the device this is going into.  However, if there will be a micrcocontroller present then you likely don't need a separate crystal driver at all.  Many microcontrollers (and just about all Microchip PICs) come with low power watch crystal oscillators.  You add the crystal and two caps, and the micro does the rest.

Yes, driving the crystal with a sine wave is the best for the crystal.

Comment: That is for digital clock, so there will be micro. The question is can it be done better than micro.

Comment: @Bars: "Better" is in relation to some spec.  If better includes low parts count, then probably no.

Comment: Surely, it's hard to do better than 0. Better = better long-term stability, less stress on the crystal